# Retrieve values from a JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I want to extract the tenantId value from the below given json

```
{
  "ClientAccounts":{
   "@tenantId":"entpriseDemo",
   "clientAccount":[
    {
     "guid":"447a0bac-51e0-4f5f-b504-97dca5825530",
     "totalValueFormatted":"$1,100,000"
    }
   ]
  }
}
```

This is my javascript function for calling an ajax request and the success function code

```
$.ajax({
      url: "$clientAccountsURL",
      cache: false,
      dataType: "json", // set to json or xml
      success: function(data){

        alert(data.ClientAccounts.tenantId);


    } 
});
```

When I'm alerting the value of tenantId in the success function it's returning me undefined value though i checked on the firebug its available in the json array.

Is there any another way to retrieve the value of tenantId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access it by using it like an associative array:

```
data.ClientAccounts['@tenantId']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the square brackets notation

```
data.ClientAccounts['@tenantId']
```

From [this mdn article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects):

> An object property name can be any valid JavaScript string, or anything that can be converted to a string, including the empty string. However, any property name that is not a valid JavaScript identifier (for example, a property name that has a space or a hyphen, or that starts with a number) can only be accessed using the square bracket notation.

Answer (score 1):

Since the property name contains an `@` you will have to access the property using the associative array syntax.

```
data.ClientAccounts["@tenantId"];
```

**JsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/VS9xe/

Answer (score 1):

You can use either object notation or and associative array notation:

In your case, use associative array notation:

```
alert(data.ClientAccounts["@tenantId"]);
```

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/2kdWQ/1/